# TypeScript checking in React Functional components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx

I am starting out with TypeScript on a React app (next.js) and I'm not sure how to type React components.

I have a component like...

```
type Props = {
  children: JSX.Element;
};

export default function SiteLayout({ children }: Props): React.FC {
return (
  <div>
    {children}
  </div>
)
```

But this gives me the following error:

> var children: JSX.Element
> Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'FC<{}>'.
> Type 'Element' provides no match for the signature '(props: { children?: ReactNode; }, context?: any): ReactElement<any, any>'.ts(2322)

I also tried to get it working with simply using `JSX.Element`:

```
type Props = {
  children: JSX.Element;
};

export default function SiteLayout({ children }: Props): JSX.Element {

return (
  <div>
    {children}
  </div>
)
```

But this gives the following error in child components.

> (alias) function SiteLayout({ children }: Props): JSX.Element
> import SiteLayout
> This JSX tag's 'children' prop expects a single child of type 'Element', but multiple children were provided.ts(2746)

The above component is being consumed in by a Next.js [page](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages) component like:

```
import Head from 'next/head';
import SiteLayout, { siteTitle } from '../../components/SiteLayout';

export default function myPage() {
  const pageTitle = 'My Page';


  return (
    <SiteLayout>
      <Head>
        <title>{siteTitle + ' - ' + pageTitle}</title>
      </Head>
      <div>
        content...
      </div>
    </SiteLayout>
  );
}
```

What is the correct approach?  I'm confused when `JSX.Element` should be used and when `React.FC` should be.

Comment: Can you please share how you are consuming the component? `React.FC` cannot be the return type. Its variable type. Also the error says about `children` and not return type

Comment: Thanks @Rajesh, I update my question. Is this enough info?

Comment: unfortunately the question is closed and still don't get it. 
Anyone know of another forum where I can get help on this? A slack channel maybe

Comment: `children: JSX.Element;` means you will have 1 child. You have more than one. Try `Array<JSX.Element>`

Comment: Thank you @Rajesh, that answers my question.  I also just tried `children: JSX.Element | any;` but `Array<JSX.Element>` is better. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The return type of the function is not a component, the function itself is component. That's why instead of

```
function SiteLayout({ children }: Props): React.FC { ...
```

It should be:

```
const SiteLayout: React.FC<Props> = ({ children }: Props) => {
    return (
      <div>
        {children}
      </div>
    );
}
```

Regarding the type of `children` prop, if there's no restriction on kind of children (string, boolean, element etc,) better to use `ReactNode`:

```
type Props = {
    children: React.ReactNode
}
```

[Here's](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L239) how it is defined.

Comment: Thanks, I got it working with...
`const SiteLayout: React.FC = ({ children }: Props) => {...}`.     
What is the reason for adding  `Props` also after `React.FC`?

Comment: Also, do you know if it has to be an arrow function assigned to a constant rather than a simple function declaration?

Comment: Yes, so you could just go with `const SiteLayout: React.FC = ({ children }) => {}` for this specific example (because `React.FC`) already types children with `{ children?: ReactNode }`

Comment: If you were adding props other than `children` - this way they were exposed to consumers of this component

Comment: Regarding function vs cont, currently there's no way to properly type functions (there're several workarounds, but I'd suggest to stick with const variant)

Comment: Relevant issue https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22063

Answer (score 0):

Your function is returning a React.FC type, which shouldnt be the case. The return type of function components is ReactNode, plus children are implicitly provided by the React.FC typing. If you explicitly type them, you can omit the React.FC and write:

```
const SiteLayout = ({children}: Props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {children}
    </div>
  )
}
```