# how to set prop type in react + typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i studied react + typescript.
i want to set component function prop type.
but i don't know how to set.

this is code.

```
interface MovieProps {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    year: number;
}

function App() {
  ...
  const movies: MovieProps[] = [
    { id:1, title: 'movie1', year: 2018 },
    { id:2, title: 'movie2', year: 2019 },
    { id:3, title: 'movie3', year: 2020 },
    { id:4, title: 'movie4', year: 2021 },
  ];
  const renderMovies: JSX.Element[] = movies.map(movie => {
    return (
      <MovieCard key={ movie['id'] } movie={ movie } />
    );
  });
    ...
}

function MovieCard({ movie }: any) {  <- this part
  return (
    <div className="movie">
      <div className="movie-title">{ movie['title'] }</div>
      <div className="movie-year">{ movie['year'] }</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

i don't want to set "any". what i set type?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript checking in React Functional components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62690259/typescript-checking-in-react-functional-components)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to pass props in react typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66586694/how-to-pass-props-in-react-typescript)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would change it so you are passing the props down to the card that you want to use instead of a container object as the prop. That makes the typing simpler too. So you can do this:

```js
interface MovieProps {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    year: number;
}

function App() {
  ...
  const movies: MovieProps[] = [
    { id:1, title: 'movie1', year: 2018 },
    { id:2, title: 'movie2', year: 2019 },
    { id:3, title: 'movie3', year: 2020 },
    { id:4, title: 'movie4', year: 2021 },
  ];
  const renderMovies: JSX.Element[] = movies.map(movie => {
    return (
      <MovieCard key={ movie.id } {...movie} />
    );
  });
    ...
}

function MovieCard({ title, year }: MovieProps) {  <- this part
  return (
    <div className="movie">
      <div className="movie-title">{ title }</div>
      <div className="movie-year">{ year }</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Just update type like this:

```
function MovieCard({ movie }: {movie: MovieProps })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows using the arrow syntax :

```
interface MovieProps {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    year: number;
}
....

const MovieCard:React.FC<MovieProps>=({ id, title, year})=> { 
  return (
    <div className="movie">
      <div className="movie-title">{ title }</div>
      <div className="movie-year">{year}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```